# How get lightning-tree to render separate component instance per each line

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tab, lightning-tabset

I have an application that utilises mix of nested tabsets and trees - see this playground: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/vXwtMddn7CcREzy4KXK4

I'd like lightning-tree to behave more like lightning-tabset - aka each of the "tab" get it's own instance. Right now my app passes `selectedGroup` which in turn fires some wire services which only work once and cause all sort of annoying side effects.

Before I go in an fork lightning-tree off github - perhaps there's a simpler way to get separate instances of component? Perhaps wrap whole tabset into separate component?

Comment: +1 for the playground example, but why does it need to be `lightning-tree` that needs to be changed? Have you looked at the vertical variant of [lightning-tabset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/example)?

Comment: Good idea and I might approach it from that aspect - we wanna display items in collapsible groups - Queues, Roles, Public Groups. So it probably easiest to add that support to open source `lightning-tabset`...

Comment: @KrisGoncalves found a way around this. Turns out pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this, full demo [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/vXwtMddn7CcREzy4KXK4/src/app.html)

TLDR - iterate instances that I wanna render and dynamically update their visibility. Keep cache of already rendered components and use css to hide ones we don't need.

Component:

```
            <lightning-tree items={groupsTree} onselect={selectGroupByEvent}>
            </lightning-tree>
            <template for:each={groupsTree} for:item="j">
                <template if:true={j.isRendered}>
                    <div class={j.isDisplayed} key={j.name}>
                        <c-child selected-group={j}>
                        </c-child>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </template>
```

Code:

```
    groupsTree = [
        {
            label: 'Group 1',
            description: 'le group uno',
            name: '1',
            expanded: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Group 2',
            description: 'le group dos',
            name: '2',
            expanded: true
        }
    ]
    rendersCache = new Set()
    selectGroupByEvent(event) {
        this.selectGroup(event.detail.name)
    }
    selectGroup(selectedGroup) {
        this.groupsTree = this.groupsTree.map(i => {
            i.isRendered = this.rendersCache.has(i.name) || i.name === selectedGroup
            if (i.isRendered) {
                this.rendersCache.add(i.name)
            }
            i.isDisplayed = i.name === selectedGroup ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide'
            return i
        })
    }
    connectedCallback(){
        this.selectGroup(this.groupsTree[0].name)
    }
```